# Feeding Twitter feeds into a web site

Tags: twitter, feed

I am building a small website for myself, and few members of a clothes user group of mine.  What I would like to do is feed the twitter feeds of my favorite designers and stores to a site, very similar to DVLPRS.com

I'm not sure if it is as simple as using rss feeds, or if it is a plugin the pulls the information from my favorite twitters.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the site ot use Twitter widgets

http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets

The site says

Widgets let you display Twitter updates on your website or social network page

So this is probably what you want for your website.